# Typesetting mathematical constants

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, best-practices

Is there any command for typesetting constants in mathematical formulas?
I would imagine something similar to `\operatorname` or `\DeclareMathOperator`, but for constants.

I want the constant to be typeset in roman font as in the text mode (with proper spacing and ligatures - this concerns constants denoted by a couple of letters).

Comment: the usual advice is to use `\mathrm{...}`.

Comment: Use `siunitx` package.

Comment: @DCh -- that's funny.  with this test, the two commands produce exactly the same result, with ligatures: `\[ x\ \mathrm{iff}\ y\ \textup{iff}\ z_{\textup{iff}}^{\mathrm{iff}} \]`.  `\mathrm` is also what's documented in lamport's latex manual.  (it can be used only in math mode, but it behaves the same as text roman; there's a reason for using `\math...` commands instead of `\text...` commands in math mode.  `\text...` commands should be used in math only within `\text{...}` according to all the documentation i've read.)

Comment: @barbara Interesting, maybe depends on typeface used..
The following demonstrates different outputs (pdflatex):
`\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}    % fix [noamsfonts] bug
\documentclass[noamsfonts]{amsart}

\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
 \[ x\ \mathrm{fin}\ y\ \textup{fin} \]
\end{document}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(updated to incorporate the comments by @egreg, barbara beaton, and @DCh)

I assume your document uses a roman (serif) font rather than a sans-serif font for mathematics. To ensure that constants are typeset consistently using upright Roman letters, it's handy to create a dedicated macro named, say, `\ct` that uses the following macros in a nested fashion: `\text` (from the `amsmath` package), `\rmfamily`(just in case the surrounding material is non-roman), and `\upshape`.

```
\newcommand\ct[1]{\text{\rmfamily\upshape #1}}
```

Then, use this macro to typeset an equation such as

```
$\ct{e}^{\ct{i}\pi}-1=0$
```

Suppose, furthermore, that your documents contains two frequently-occurring constants named `ab-cd` and `fi-fi`. (You did say that the names of the constants might contain ligatures...) To help speed up typing, you could define two macros `\abcd` and `\fifi` as follows:

```
\newcommand*{\abcd}{\ct{ab-cd}}
\newcommand*{\fifi}{\ct{fi-fi}}
```

The result of a full MWE:

[image]

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\documentclass[noamsfonts]{amsart}  \usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

%% use the \ct macro to define math constants
\newcommand\ct[1]{\text{\rmfamily\upshape #1}}

%% define two math constants with rather contrived names...
\newcommand{\abcd}{\ct{ab-cd}}
\newcommand{\fifi}{\ct{fi-fi}}

\begin{document} 
\sffamily  % switch to sans-serif for main text font

$\ct{e}^{\ct{i}\piup}-1=0$,
$(\abcd)^2-\ct{e}^{(\fifi^3)}=0$

not in math mode: ab-cd, fi-fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathrm`, not `\textup`.

Comment: In case of a sans serif or small caps context, `\textup` would respect it, while `\mathrm` wouldn't.

Comment: @egreg -- try the test provided in the second comment by DCh to the question.  (i just did.)  indeed, as he claims, the results are different -- i suspect he's right that it may depend on what fonts are being used, because i can't think of any other reason.  (i tried it with both `amsart` and `article` to make sure the former wasn't a factor.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The only difference is that the `fi` ligature is not made with `\mathrm`, which is expected.

Comment: @egreg -- but the ligatures *are* made with `\mathrm` when computer modern is used.  that may be unexpected, but when i checked several other strings, including "ffl", the ligatures are clearly present.

Comment: @egreg -- so, if charter is being used, does that imply that `\mathrm` should *not* be used if a ligatured "word" is wanted?  if so, then a lot of latex documentation is "off", or (at the very least) incomplete.  (or is the decision for charter's italic correction at variance with the (la)tex design goals?)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The situation is different; with `mathdesign`, `\mathrm` uses the `lettersupright` symbol font, which is mapped to `mdbchr7m`, which has no `f` ligature (no ligatures at all, to be precise).

Comment: @egreg @barbarabeeton OK, did I get this correctly:
`\mathrm` should be used for (both single and multi character) constants? However, charter is flawed and needs to be handled exceptionally?
(I would still appreciate some higher level command for constants, a companion of `\operatorname` which would take care hyphens, ligatures,..)

Comment: @DCh - I've updated my answer to reflect various comments, including your own ones. I now think it's best to use `\textrm` -- not `\mathrm`, not `\textup` -- when defining math constants. To wit, `\textrm` preserves ligatures, simple dashes (i.e., they don't get typeset a minus signs), and spaces in the names of the constants.

Comment: @Mico (and others) Thanks, your help is appreciated!
One minor thing: IIRC according to ISO standards, π should also be in upright in the context of your MWE. With `mathdesign` e.g. `\piup` should work.

Comment: @Mico I don't think that `\textrm` is a good choice. It respects settings for text mode. Thus e.g. gets slanted in statements of theorems, which is very undesirable.

Comment: @DCh - Wow, you're very thorough! Please see the yet-again-updated answer for what I hope is a (more) robust solution. Let me know if you're satisfied -- or not...

Comment: @Mico Sorry for that, just pointing out issues as I encounter them. Also we should get this right if it is be a model example.
Have to admit, not very pleased with the solution, but there probably isn't a better one. Having to use 3 commands just to ensure proper constant identifier behavior just does not feel right. `amsopn` package takes care of this, but only for operators.

Comment: @DCh - Don't feel bad about the complexity that underlies the `\ct` macro: it's the need to accommodate dashes, ligatures, and spaces in the constants' names that makes the macro less simple than `amsopn`'s approach (which, by design, won't handle those "features").

Comment: I reopened the question because I encountered another issue with the present solution. The `\ct` macro does not work properly when used e.g. within `\section` as the intended constant gets typeset in small caps.

Comment: @DCh - Instead of "reopening" this four-year-old question -- sadly, very few people will notice that you did so (mainly by revoking the previously-awarded "accept" badge, right?) -- it would have been better if you had posted a *new question*. The issue you've encountered appears to be sufficiently distinct to merit being raised in a new question; that way, far more people will get to see it and have a chance to think about providing an answer.